# Can client and employee be in the same pool?

Tags: bpmn

Suppose a client wants to be able to create a trusted profile (sort of like a digital signature).  The client creates their account, fills out the application and then confirms it so an employee can verify their identity and create the trusted profile.

Is it alright for both the client and employee to be in the same pool, or should they be in distinct pools such that only messages can pass between the two?

[image: Image demonstrating the idea]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct pools. There are several aspects supporting this:

- The client typically does not belong to the same organisation/system, thus it should be modelled as a separate pool.
- The application form is a document that is handed over from the client to the point of confirmation. The semantics of handing over a document or form is equivalent to passing a message to another party. Message passing makes it very explicit, which data is being passed. When using sequence flow, it is less clear (although you could attach a data object to the flow).

Besides of those points, I stumbled upon the first "Logging" task, which seems to be modelled from a very technical perspective. I'd rather model an activity "Check if client account exists", then have a gateway that decides whether an account needs to be created or not and then proceed. The case that the account is not existent is IMO a very valid case from a business perspective and not to be considered an exception/error.

Comment: Thanks for answer. About "logging" you mentioned it was like that in the first version so I guess I should not change it :). Now about distinct pools - client has to physically go to the point of confirmations to confirm his id so can there be just a message flow from "Creating trusted profile" subprocess to "Creating trusted profile for client" ?

Comment: That would be bad style. When connecting collapsed subprocesses with message flow, this implies that there are elements within the subprocess that are connected as well. To me it is unclear why there are expanded subprocesses in the model. IMO the end event in the upper subprocess should be a throwing message event, connected via message flow to a catching message start event in the lower lane, which is then supposed to be a pool. Please note that each pool needs to have their own start and end events, or none of them respectively.

Comment: Considering that employee and client are different pools can I just connect "going to the point of confirmations to confirm the identity" to "verificate the identity" via message flow ? Would "going to the..." be user or message task in that case?